# Why is my connection string failing?

Tags: .net, sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-express, sqlclient

Does anybody have any reason this would fail on a local DB?

```
connectionString="Data Source=localhost\MSSQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=K2Consulting;User Id=domain\myUser;Password=Password;Pooling=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: in what way does it fail? What error do you get? P.S. your tags are wrong this is nothing to do with MySQL. I'll correct it.

Comment: do you use `mysql` or `mssql`?  in your Connection string you use mssql, your post is tagged as mysql

Comment: Sorry! Literally first time here. Thanks for being so cool about it. This is MSSQL. I thought it was an interest tag.

Comment: You cannot use domain accounts (`domain\user`) with SQL Server authentication. Either use `Integrated Security=SSPI` with no user name and password to let Windows take care of authenticating you, or supply a user name and password, but then create that account separately as a SQL Server account. (And never set something like `Pooling=false` unless you *really* know what you're doing -- connection pooling is a Good Thing, and only broken software should need it disabled.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks a ton!